# Slicknav mobile menu does not work on Blackberry 10 devices

Tags: jquery, mobile, menu, blackberry-10, slicknav

we are developing a website: http://2mholdings.squaresystem.co.uk/.

It's a responsive website and we are using a jQuery Plugin for the mobile menu called 'slickNav'.
I've found that it works reliably on all devices except for Blackberry 10 devices (other Blackberrys work no problem).

The issue is that a Blackberry 10 user cannot select the menu to get it to dropdown and click through to other pages whatsoever.
We do not have a Blackberry 10 device in the office to test this either which makes it even more troublesome.

Can anybody help/advise?

Comment: Well it works right now. I suppose you fixed it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the [Blackberry 10 simulator](http://developer.blackberry.com/develop/simulator/simulator_installing.html)? I have tested [SlickNav.com](http://slicknav.com) on it and all drop downs work correctly.

It looks as if you need to remove `position:fixed` from `.slicknav_nav` in your slicknav.css since you already have `#mob-nav` fixed.

Comment: Well, spotted I have removed the `position: fixed`. I don't think that will make any difference though. I have tried it. But, if it works fine in Blackberry 10 simulator then that won't help diagnose the issue for me.

Comment: @JHair, I was stating that the SlickNav site was fine on the simulator and therefore the plugin works on BB10, but your site exhibited the behavior you described. Once I changed the CSS values, your site behaved correctly.

Comment: I see thanks for clearing it up, I understand what you're saying now. I made this change and sent it back to the client, they have not mentioned it since so I'm going to make the assumption it worked based on what you said. Thanks